# How to specify order of dependent tasks?

Tags: sbt

I have a task that must call other tasks in sequence.

```
val taskA = taskDef[Unit]("....")
val taskB = taskDef[Unit]("....")
val taskC = taskDef[Unit]("....")
val taskD = taskDef[Unit]("....")

taskA := {
    taskB.value
    taskC.value
    taskD.value
}

taskB := {
    ...
}

taskC := {
    ...
}

taskD := {
    ...
}
```

The result is that although `taskB`, `taskC` and `taskD` are indeed called before `taskA`, I can't seem to find a way to control their order, i.e. `taskD` can be called before `taskC`.

How can I specify the running order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use `dependsOn` method of a setting combined with `<<=`:

```
val taskA = taskDef[Unit]("....")
val taskB = taskDef[Unit]("....")
val taskC = taskDef[Unit]("....")
val taskD = taskDef[Unit]("....")

taskA := {},

taskB := {
    ...
},

taskC := {
    ...
},

taskD := {
    ...
},
taskA <<= taskA.dependsOn(taskD),

taskD <<= taskA.dependsOn(taskC),

taskC <<= taskA.dependsOn(taskB),
```